# Polling for a Bluetooth Button Push

Tags: linux, usb, console, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth button that I have successfully paired several times with various raspberry pi's and linux boxes.  The button works as a unique doorbell and various other applications, but I have one box that is being troublesome with it as the radios between the button and the linux box is rather chatty.  My current button press detection is a complete cheat (and works by polling `hciconfig hci0` for traffic every second) but I've come to the point where I have to actually do this correctly, hence why I am asking here.

The button is [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RM75NOW).

And it's recognized:

```
user@linux:/$ hciconfig                                                                             
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB                                                                                  
        BD Address: 00:21:5C:AF:DB:87  ACL MTU: 1021:5  SCO MTU: 96:6                                                   
        UP RUNNING PSCAN                                                                                                
        RX bytes:20633 acl:535 sco:0 events:1331 errors:0                                                               
        TX bytes:7835 acl:344 sco:0 commands:401 errors:0
```

I know from experimentation that the push sends a `^@`... and I know that because that's what it sends to the console when pushed.  But I need to intercept that in a script to be able to run a script.  Any advice?

Comment: BTW, Ubuntu 14.04 is the system in question here.